# Exceptions in C#

Tags: c#, exception, reflection

I am trying to write a well-documented code that will be also easy to debug if some exception is handled. Therefore my methods throw exceptions and they're gathered in the log that I can browse. However, it is not really suitable to write complex messages when throwing a new exception. I would like to write a simple utility that would gather:

- name of the current class
- name of the current method
- parameters of the method

Can this be achieved in some easy way? Also, is there a better way to make such logs of exceptions? Perhaps this issue is being solved in a different way, so please share your experience with me :)

Comment: Well there's the StackTrace, already included with an exception, which is pretty much that..

Comment: In this format your question is too broad. Also it is better to store/log the stack trace on exception. You can look in the web how to take stack trace.

Comment: @Pierre-Luc Pineault Wonderful! I didn't know it exists. Thank you :) If you write it as an answer, I will give you the check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An exception already contains this information in its [`StackTrace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.stacktrace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

To get access to it, simply use the public getter:

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
    string trace = ex.StackTrace;
}
```

If you want to log it, most loggers have an overload which takes an exception. The message and stack trace will be logged.

For example, with log4net, you can use the method `void Error(object message, Exception t);`:

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
    logger.Error("More details", ex);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

hi to get the name of the method with signatures the fix is

```
        //get the stack trace 
        StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
        //the count may vary
        MethodBase CallingMethod = stackTrace.GetFrame(2).GetMethod();

        //Method called by                    
        string _signatures = MethodInfoExtensions.GetSignature((MethodInfo)CallingMethod));
```

and the class

```
public static class MethodInfoExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Return the method signature as a string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="method">The Method</param>
    /// <param name="callable">Return as an callable string(public void a(string b) would return a(b))</param>
    /// <returns>Method signature</returns>
    public static string GetSignature(this MethodInfo method, bool callable = false)
    {
        var firstParam = true;
        var sigBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        if (callable == false)
        {
            if (method.IsPublic)
                sigBuilder.Append("public ");
            else if (method.IsPrivate)
                sigBuilder.Append("private ");
            else if (method.IsAssembly)
                sigBuilder.Append("internal ");
            if (method.IsFamily)
                sigBuilder.Append("protected ");
            if (method.IsStatic)
                sigBuilder.Append("static ");
            sigBuilder.Append(TypeName(method.ReturnType));
            sigBuilder.Append(' ');
        }
        sigBuilder.Append(method.Name);

        // Add method generics
        if (method.IsGenericMethod)
        {
            sigBuilder.Append("<");
            foreach (var g in method.GetGenericArguments())
            {
                if (firstParam)
                    firstParam = false;
                else
                    sigBuilder.Append(", ");
                sigBuilder.Append(TypeName(g));
            }
            sigBuilder.Append(">");
        }
        sigBuilder.Append("(");
        firstParam = true;
        var secondParam = false;
        foreach (var param in method.GetParameters())
        {
            if (firstParam)
            {
                firstParam = false;
                if (method.IsDefined(typeof(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute), false))
                {
                    if (callable)
                    {
                        secondParam = true;
                        continue;
                    }
                    sigBuilder.Append("this ");
                }
            }
            else if (secondParam == true)
                secondParam = false;
            else
                sigBuilder.Append(", ");
            if (param.ParameterType.IsByRef)
                sigBuilder.Append("ref ");
            else if (param.IsOut)
                sigBuilder.Append("out ");
            if (!callable)
            {
                sigBuilder.Append(TypeName(param.ParameterType));
                sigBuilder.Append(' ');
            }
            sigBuilder.Append(param.Name);
        }
        sigBuilder.Append(")");
        return sigBuilder.ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get full type name with full namespace names
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type">Type. May be generic or nullable</param>
    /// <returns>Full type name, fully qualified namespaces</returns>
    public static string TypeName(Type type)
    {
        var nullableType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type);
        if (nullableType != null)
            return nullableType.Name + "?";

        if (!type.IsGenericType)
            switch (type.Name)
            {
                case "String": return "string";
                case "Int32": return "int";
                case "Decimal": return "decimal";
                case "Object": return "object";
                case "Void": return "void";
                default:
                    {
                        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(type.FullName) ? type.Name : type.FullName;
                    }
            }

        var sb = new StringBuilder(type.Name.Substring(0,
        type.Name.IndexOf('`'))
        );
        sb.Append('<');
        var first = true;
        foreach (var t in type.GetGenericArguments())
        {
            if (!first)
                sb.Append(',');
            sb.Append(TypeName(t));
            first = false;
        }
        sb.Append('>');
        return sb.ToString();
    }

}
```